# Помогите доработать код C# для ZENNOPOSTER'a

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте Уважаемые Эксперты! Возможно немного не по теме форума, но всё же... имеется вот такой вот код для программы zennoposter, так называемый сниппет на C#:

```
Size ImgSize = new Size(400, 400); //размеры готовой картинки
string img1 = project.Variables["img_url"].Value; // адрес картинки жертвы
string saveDir = project.Variables["dir_name"].Value; //папка куда сохранять результат
Bitmap foreImg = new Bitmap(@"E:/ZP-prdj/1.png"); // адрес вотемарка
Bitmap backImg = new Bitmap(img1);
byte s = 255;
// ImgSize = обе исходные картинки приводятся к указанному размеру
// s прозрачность накладываемого изображения foreImg от 0 (100%) до 255 (0%)
// результат наследует Альфа-канал фонового изображения
// наложение использует Альфа-канал накладываемого изображения
Bitmap fimg = new Bitmap(foreImg, ImgSize);
Bitmap bimg = new Bitmap(backImg, ImgSize);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ImgSize.Width, ImgSize.Height);
for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Width; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Height; j++)
{
Color fm = fimg.GetPixel(i, j);
Color bm = bimg.GetPixel(i, j);
byte af = (byte)(fm.A * s / byte.MaxValue);
byte a = bm.A;
byte r = (byte)((fm.R * af + bm.R * (byte.MaxValue - af)) / byte.MaxValue);
byte g = (byte)((fm.G * af + bm.G * (byte.MaxValue - af)) / byte.MaxValue);
byte b = (byte)((fm.B * af + bm.B * (byte.MaxValue - af)) / byte.MaxValue);
bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
}

bmp.Save(@"E:/ZP-prdj/"+saveDir+"/img_new.jpg");
```

по идее должен работать но выдает ошибку:

[image: скриншот ошибки из zenoposter'a]

помогите пожалуйста поправить код и исправить ошибку. Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: оберни все в [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, zennoposter не любит, когда Disposable-переменные живут слишком долго.

Оберните упомянутые переменные в using:

```
Size ImgSize = new Size(400, 400); //размеры готовой картинки
string img1 = project.Variables["img_url"].Value; // адрес картинки жертвы
string saveDir = project.Variables["dir_name"].Value; //папка куда сохранять результат
using (Bitmap foreImg = new Bitmap(@"E:/ZP-prdj/1.png") // адрес вотемарка
{
using (Bitmap backImg = new Bitmap(img1)
{

byte s = 255;
// ImgSize = обе исходные картинки приводятся к указанному размеру
// s прозрачность накладываемого изображения foreImg от 0 (100%) до 255 (0%)
// результат наследует Альфа-канал фонового изображения
// наложение использует Альфа-канал накладываемого изображения
using (Bitmap fimg = new Bitmap(foreImg, ImgSize))
{
    using (Bitmap bimg = new Bitmap(backImg, ImgSize))
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ImgSize.Width, ImgSize.Height))
        {
            // циклы

            bmp.Save(@"E:/ZP-prdj/"+saveDir+"/img_new.jpg");
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: там он как раз на `foreImg` ругался, поэтому все бы надо обернуть :-)

Comment: @Grundy дообернул :)

Comment: We need more using inside using :)

Comment: кстати, так как тут один тип, все их можно в один юзинг сунуть

Comment: @Grundy так читабельнее :) (если вообще может быть читабельным код, работающий с 5-ю битмапами одновременно)

Comment: Я кстати не совсем понял зачем создавать вторые битмапы с переданным размером, почему не сразу размер передать?

Comment: всё равно не работает, теперь другую ошибку выдает - Выполнение действия CSharp OwnCode The path is not of a legal form

Comment: видимо using не нужно указывать в этом коде, т.к. using'и все указываются отдельно, вот например для моего проекта какие using'и указаны: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

Comment: using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using ZennoLab.CommandCenter;
using ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary;
using ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.ProjectModel;
using ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.ProjectModel.Collections;
using ZennoLab.InterfacesLibrary.ProjectModel.Enums;
using ZennoLab.Macros;
using Global.ZennoExtensions;
using ZennoLab.Emulation;
видимо здесь нужно указать дополнительные параметры, а вот какие...

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры это же другие юзинги! :)

Comment: я знаю что это другие, у меня ведь там еще код есть. Дело в том, что я не знаю как правильно исправить ошибку. Помогите пожалуйста  кто знаком с zennoposter'oм

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры вам написали как это делается.

Comment: я благодарен @PashaPash за измененный код, но к сожалению такой вариант не работает. Первоначальная ошибка ушла, но сам зеннопостер ругается именно на такое решение, т.к. using'и указываются в другом месте, там и нужно указать нужные параметры. Как это сделать я не пойму.

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры это не те using-и. те, что указываются в другом месте - это подключения namespace. эти - автоматический вызов Dispose.

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры The path is not of a legal form - скорее всего из-за того, что у вас пути указываются с неправильным слешем. указывайте с прямым - `"C:\\Something"` или `@"C:\Something"`